# Is CoreData suitable for searching against large amounts of data?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, core-data

In my iPad application, I download a large amount of customer and order history information, which I keep in memory and use throughout the application. For some users, however, the amount of data downloaded becomes so large that the app crashes.

I have just set up a CoreData store to write all of the customer and order data to disk. Before I go any further though, is CoreData the best way to go about this? I need to be able to sort these data sets by a number of parameters and drive tableviews with them (which CoreData seems well-suited for), but I also need to look at the entire data set to drive other views. For example, an alphabet filter which only displays the letters for which I have results.

Comment: Define "large" and also, please give information about what data you are dealing with.

Comment: I haven't done a thorough analysis but I know it's over a gig for the users that end up crashing the application. The data is pretty typical for customers (name, a few address fields, email address, some other metadata), orders (customer metadata, pricing info, order items), and order items (SKU, price, qty ordered, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Core Data is definitely the technology of choice. You will find that you can quite easily solve all the problems and implement all the features you mention.

As far as optimization for data manipulation on iOS goes (both performance and memory), Core Data is really a very robust and well-tested framework. If you want to max out the capacity of the iOS device, there is hardly anything better.

As an example, quite recently I have been involved in a project (also involving large amounts of customer data) that was a few years old and simply hit a wall when it came to managing memory, speed and complexity. Refactoring for Core Data was a snap, and the performance gains are immense.

The reason for Core Data's success is the fact that it completely hides the database layer and focuses on the object graph. This leads to much more readable and maintainable code (as opposed to SQL statements). While you could theoretically use several kinds of stores with Core Data, the  most common one is SQLite, the database with the *largest number of installations in the world*. It is ubiquitous on mobile devices because of its speed and small footprint.

This leads me to conclude that Core Data is the way to go for you.

Comment: @pst added more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

i recently ported my app from straight sqlite to core data with an sqlite backing store. i have a reasonable sized database of around 100,000 records. i've also spent a significant amount of time optimizing it

Despite all the apple doc and pr saying its efficient, fast etc etc. what i've found is that when compared to straight sqlite, for large amounts of data it does have higher memory requirements and is significantly slower. a quick search on stack overflow will confirm this. there are a lot of unresolved questions about the speed, memory requirements etc.

in particular, insertions and deletions are orders of magnitude slower. fetches generally use more memory than straight sqlite. in most cases core data pulls more data. for example in straight sqlite you can pull an integer id, then pull the rest of the data when needed. coredata pulls more data do do that. deletions require you to pull the data down before deleting it etc.

if you need to encrypt your data. this is a challenge in core data and no one has really been able to provide reliable encryption while not breaking things such as nspredicates.
whether or not it requires less code to be written is debatable.
there is definitely a steep learning curve. the core data way of thinking is very different from a relational database one.

so why would you use core data? its the additional features, support for undo, batch fetching, manages object updates for you and syncing to iCloud (though this is very buggy to the point that its unusable right now) etc etc. Some things it does for you. you don't need to manage primary keys, relationships etc etc.
In the apple ecosystem it seems future proof given new features such as icloud support are being built into core data. Though it does kill your portability if you want to go to android etc.